# Create full height line inside Bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container, within which is a row of columns. I am trying to create 3 columns with fields and a full height vertical separator between each. I am using 24 column grid system with Bootstrap.

I can't seem to get the line to dynamically go full height; tried playing with parent div's height, absolute positioning, etc...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
      content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 vertical-stroke">
  <div class="col-md-7">
      content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 vertical-stroke">
  <div class="col-md-7">
      content
  </div>
```

Two concepts I've been playing with are:

```
.vertical-stroke {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Above causing everything to get out of whack, displaying a giant line not at all where I intended.

and below, which displays a very short line... even though it's parent div is the full row which has a much taller height

```
.vertical-stroke {
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

1) How can I create a full height vertical line?

Comment: have you tried setting border-right: 1px solid red or something like this. ?

Comment: col-* takes the height of its own content, so one solution would be to try to make the columns full-height...